# How do I properly handle DDC metadata and settings?

Tags: redhawksdr

Using REDHAWK Version 2.0.5,

Given a CHANNELIZER centered at 300MHz and a DDC attached to the CHANNELIZER centered at 301MHz. The DDC is set relative to the CHANNELIZER and in this case the DDC is centered at a 1MHz offset from the CHANNELIZER.

A) How should I present the DDC center frequency to a user in the frontend tuner status and allocation? For example, would they enter 1MHz or 301MHz to set the center frequency for the DDC? Currently I am using the latter version.

B) In version 2.1.0 of the REDHAWK manual in section F.5.2 it says the COL_RF SRI keyword is the center frequency of the collector and the CHAN_RF is the center frequency of the stream. In the above case, I set COL_RF to 300MHz and CHAN_RF to 301MHz but the REDHAWK IDE plots center at 300MHz for the DDC. Should the CHAN_RF be a relative value such as 1MHz? Currently, at 301MHz, the IDE plots appear to center at the COL_RF frequency of 300MHz.

C) When the CHANNELIZER center frequency changes, I only set the valid field in the allocation to false on attached DDCs. Is there any other special bookkeeping that needs to be done when this happens?

D) Should disabling or enabling the output from the CHANNELIZER also disable or enable the output for the attached DDCs?

E) Must deallocating the CHANNELIZER force all DDCs that are attached to deallocate?

Answer (score 1):

A) All external interfaces (allocation, `FrontendTuner` ports, status properties, etc) assume RF values, not IF or offsets. Allocate or tune to 301MHz in order to center a `DDC` at 301MHz. The `center_frequency` field of the `frontend_tuner_status` property should be set to 301MHz for that `DDC`.

B) Your understanding of how to use `COL_RF` (300MHz) and `CHAN_RF` (301MHz) is correct. You may be able to work around this by reordering the SRI keywords to have `CHAN_RF` appear first, if necessary.

For (C) and (D), there are some design decisions that are left up to the developer since the implementation, as well as the hardware (if any), may impact those decisions. Here are some recommendations, though.

C) In general, if at any point the `DDC`s become invalid, they should be marked as such. It is possible to retune a `CHANNELIZER` by a small amount such that one or more `DDC`s still fall within the frequency range and remain valid, but that may also be hardware dependent. Additionally, it's recommended that `DDC`s only produce data when both enabled AND valid, so if marking invalid you may also want to stop producing data from the invalid `DDC`s.

D) `CHANNELIZER` and `RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER` tuners both have wideband input and narrowband `DDC` output. Some implementations of an `RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER` may have the ability to produce wideband digital output of the analog input (acting as an `RX_DIGITIZER`). In this scenario, the `RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER` output enable/disable controls the wideband output, while the `DDC`s output enable remain independently controlled. The behavior of a `CHANNELIZER`, which does not produce wideband output, is left as a design decision for the developer. For behavior consistent with `RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER` tuners, it's recommended that the `DDC`s remain independently controlled. Note that the enable for a tuner is specifically the output enable, and not an overall enable/disable of the tuner itself. For that reason, it's recommended that the enable for a `CHANNELIZER` not affect the data flow to the `DDC`s since that data flow is internal to the device. Again, this is all up to the developer and these are just recommendations since the spec leaves it open.

E) Yes, deallocating a `CHANNELIZER` should result in deallocation of all associated `DDC`s.

Comment: See also https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-gov.redhawk.core/commit/c3277f3955662b424957f94844c80dd2adbb5f8c regarding part B.